# Decompose json array string in Logstash

Tags: arrays, json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a RabbitMQ sending 3 fields in JSON format and it is being consumed by Logstash rabbitmq input plugin.

One of the fields is a JSON array of strings as follows:

```
"content": [
  "1111",
  "2222222",
  "Test 06",
  "3",
  "3232",
  "SomeValue1"
]
```

1. How could I make each entry of that string into a field so that I can quickly discover and visualize in Kibana from the available fields? Right now I see "content" with that full string.
2. The JSON array string size changes depending on another field, eventID. Would it be possible to dynamically map the values in that string to specific names depending on the eventID?
   Such as:

   ```
   "eventID": 1,
     "content": [
     "name1": "1111",
     "name2": "2222222",
     "name3": "Test 06",
     "name4": "3",
     "name5": "3232",
     "name6": "SomeValue1"
   ]

   "eventID": 2,
     "content": [
     "othername1": "3434",
     "othername2": "Test 10",
     "othername3": "876",
     "othername4": "Some String7"
   ]
   ```

I would like to have the name* and othername* in the available fields. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume for a moment that your input is properly parsed as an array already.  For testing purposes, that means that this:

```
echo '{"eventID":1,"content":["a","b","c","d"]}' | bin/logstash -f test.conf
```

where test.conf is:

```
input {
    stdin { codec => json }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

will output this:

```
{
       "eventID" => 1,
    "@timestamp" => 2017-08-03T19:39:13.054Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxx.local",
       "content" => [
        [0] "a",
        [1] "b",
        [2] "c",
        [3] "d"
    ]
}
```

If that's the case, then you'll need to do something like this:

```
filter {
    if [eventID] == 1 {
        mutate {
            add_field => {
                "eventName" => "type1 event"
                "one0" => "%{[content][0]}"
                "one1" => "%{[content][1]}"
                "one2" => "%{[content][2]}"
                "one3" => "%{[content][3]}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "content" ]
        }
    } else if [eventID] == 2 {
        mutate {
            add_field => {
                "eventName" => "type2 event"
                "two0" => "%{[content][0]}"
                "two1" => "%{[content][1]}"
                "two2" => "%{[content][2]}"
                "two3" => "%{[content][3]}"
            }
            remove_field => [ "content" ]
        }
    }
}
```

which will generate an event like this:

```
{
       "eventID" => 1,
    "@timestamp" => 2017-08-03T19:51:02.946Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxx.local",
          "one2" => "c",
     "eventName" => "type1 event",
          "one3" => "d",
          "one0" => "a",
          "one1" => "b"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try it soon but the tests so far were very good. Once quick question though, is it possible to auto increment the X in "oneX" (i.e. one1, one2, one3....) because some events are not fixed length and I don't want to miss any values. Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to resort to a ruby filter to do that since logstash has no concept of a loop counter or anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. I am just struggling to figure out how to dynamically add (oneX...) from that event that has variable size.

Comment: I would rather have it dynamically generated but I could have the first value fixed and the rest in a key string array. Such as "eventName" => "type1 event"
"one0" => "%{[content][0]}"
"one1" => "%{[content][1,2,3,etc]}" <- all remainder content

Comment: a ruby filter to do it would looks something like: `event.get('content').each_with_index | v, i | (newline) event.set("whatev#{i}",v) (newline) end`

Comment: I tried something like this but my ruby knowledge is very limited. event.get('content').each_with_index { |v,i| event.set['whatev_' + (i+1).to_s] = v } Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Expected one of #, {, } etc

Comment: You’ve got square brackets on the set. It should be parens. And you can put the I+1 in the {} from my example instead of just i

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much.

Comment: how would I skip the first array value and only get the other ones through the each_with_index

Comment: if i > 0 event.set... end?

Comment: thank you again. it works like a charm. Just troubleshooting one last thing here. Under the remove_field I added a convert convert      => { "two2" => "integer" } but Kibana only sees it as a string instead of a number. I already deleted the index but no idea why it doesn't work.