# How to extract values within square brackets fields in a json log

Tags: json, syntax, logstash, brackets, square

i am a newbie in the use of logstash and i need help with the following json log format:

```
{
"field1" :[
{
"sub_field1": {
"sub_field2":"value X"
"sub_field3": {"sub_field4":"value Y"}

}
"sub_field5":"value W"
}
]
}
```

i want to know how to get Value X,Value Y and Value W using the mutate: "Add_field".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you will only have one array element under `field1`, it's just:

```
add_field => {
  sub_field1 => '%{[field1][0][sub_field1]}'
  sub_field2 => '%{[field1][0][sub_field1][sub_field2]}'
...
}
```

A good way to test this -- create a file called `test.json`

```
{ "field1" :[ { "sub_field1": { "sub_field2":"value X","sub_field3": {"sub_field4":"value Y"} }, "sub_field5":"value W" } ] }
```

Create a config file like `test.conf`:

```
{
    stdin { codec => 'json_lines' }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            sub_field1 => '%{[field1][0][sub_field1]}'
            sub_field2 => '%{[field1][0][sub_field1][sub_field2]}'
        }
    }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => "rubydebug" }
}
```

And then run it: `cat test.json | bin/logstash -f test.conf`

You'll get output like this:

```
{
        "field1" => [
        [0] {
            "sub_field5" => "value W",
            "sub_field1" => {
                "sub_field3" => {
                    "sub_field4" => "value Y"
                },
                "sub_field2" => "value X"
            }
        }
    ],
    "@timestamp" => 2020-02-17T17:26:59.471Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxxx",
    "sub_field2" => "value X",
    "sub_field1" => "{\"sub_field3\":{\"sub_field4\":\"value Y\"},\"sub_field2\":\"value X\"}",
          "tags" => []
}
```

Which shows `sub_field2` and `sub_field1`.

If you don't predictable field names then you'll need to resort to a ruby filter or something like that.  And if you have more than one element you need to spit out, you'll need to use a strategy that's discussed in the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45493411/2785358

Comment: Thank you for the reply Alcanzar, weirdly its not working.
When i use the stdout to see the output, i visualize the [0],[1] of the array but even using the format [field1][0][sub_field] its not giving me the information. Any hint what could be?

Comment: It works for me -- will update answer with a bit more

Comment: My log is around 100 lines, i dont know if it helps if i post it here.

Comment: Reduce it to a minimal possible configuration like I've shown -- take one line of input, create a test config file, and then look at the result and adjust.

Comment: Hi Alcanzar, sorry for the stupid question but when i configure my test.conf and execute the command : cat /usr/share/logstash/test.json | bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf


it stops on the: 

[INFO ] 2020-02-17 15:30:42.194 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9601}
[INFO ] 2020-02-17 15:30:42.538 [LogStash::Runner] runner - Logstash shut down.



and does not show the output, any idea why it happens?

Comment: my test was done with logstash 5 (because that's what I had available on my computer at the moment)... what version are you using?  Assuming some 7.x version?

Comment: i tested on 7.6 and my method works there as well... (at least when the test.json and test.conf are in the current directory and I'm in the directory that I unzip'd logstash to)... it outputs a lot more, but it does work... make sure you have the input/output sections in the test.conf as well so that you can use stdin/stdout to see what's going on

Comment: yes, correct. I using 7.6 version. Also, regarding the field i looking for inside the array, it repeats 5 times but in the json i see the identication number after the "open" square bracket:[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]. So could this be the reason its not working? also the field is float type, i dont know if it helps. if you want i can upload somewhere a sample output just for better compreehension.

Comment: in my example, there's just one element in the `fields1` array --- if you are seeing [1], [2], [3], [4], you've got multiple values in the array and so it'll only pull out the [0] element.  If you are trying to seperate those out toe different events, you're in for a bit more work -- you'll have to use the `split` filter to convert the array into different events.